# Build a dictionary from .txt files analysis

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp

I have a basic program that can count the number of words in a given text file. I am trying to turn this into a program that can take in several different .txt files, with an arbitrary amount of keywords within those file analyzed, and output a dictionary within a list of the results (or similar object).

The output I am looking for is a list of dictionaries wherein the list keys are the names of the .txt files in the filenames list, and the dictionary keys-values are the arbitrary words within the first function and their words counts, respectively.

I have two function that I have created and cannot seem to get any out whatsoever - which means that somethin n.

Code:

```
def word_count(filename, *selected_words):
    """Count the approximate number of words in a file."""
    with open(filename,"r",encoding='utf-8') as f_obj:
            contents = f_obj.read()
    filename = {} 
    filename['document'] = filename 
    filename['total_words'] = len(contents.split()) 
       
    for word in selected_words:
        count =  contents.lower().count(word)
        filename[word] = count
    return filename

def analysis_output():
    for file in files:
        word_count(file, 'the', 'yes') #WORD_COUNT FUNCTION 

files = ['alice.txt', 'siddhartha.txt', 
'moby_dick.txt', 'little_women.txt']

analysis_output()
```

When I run this, I am not getting any output - no errors telling me the code has run (likely improperly). Any advice on how to turn this into a a list of dictionaries is helpful!

Comment: Nesting dictionaries within a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot to define a variable to receive the output from `word_count`. In fact, you can do it this way:

```py
def word_count(filename, *selected_words):
    """Count the approximate number of words in a file."""
    with open(filename,"r",encoding='utf-8') as f_obj:
            contents = f_obj.read()
    results_dict = {} 
    results_dict['document'] = filename 
    results_dict['total_words'] = len(contents.split()) 
       
    for word in selected_words:
        count =  contents.lower().count(word)
        results_dict[word] = count
    return results_dict

def analysis_output():
    output = []
    for file in files:
        output.append(word_count(file, 'the', 'yes')) #WORD_COUNT FUNCTION 
    return output

files = ['alice.txt', 'siddhartha.txt', 
'moby_dick.txt', 'little_women.txt']

final_result = analysis_output()
```

Comment: Seems to be getting very close. Am now getting a syntax error on the last return:
```
File "<ipython-input-11-3d880e747d30>", line 6
    return output
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I copy and paste it on my machine and it returns no error. I suggest to check the indentation in front of the `return output` if it is a tab or 4 white-spaces.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was just missing a single parenthesis in the  for loop on my machine. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

My solution below solves your problem in a slightly different way. I am using lists and strings only, no dictionaries. I've entered extra comments, if needed - I hope you will find it useful.

```
def get_words_string(file_name):
    """get a lower-case string of all words from a file"""
    try:
        with open(file_name,"r",encoding='utf-8') as file_object:
            contents = file_object.read().lower()
            return contents
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f'File not found')

def count_words(words_string, *words_to_count):
    '''counts a number of each *words_to_count in a words_string'''
    for word in words_to_count:
        print(f'{word} occurs {words_string.count(word)} times')

files = [
    'text files/alice.txt',
    'text files/moby_dick.txt',
    'text files/pride_and_pre.txt',
    ]

for file in files:
        print(file)
        #try block just in case if file is missing 
        #so the program can continue
        try:
            count_words(get_words_string(file), 'yes', 'the', 'cat', 'honour')
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Adding in the exception is a good idea. thank you for this.